# Vaadin 14 browser Multi-tab supported

Tags: asynchronous, browser, vaadin, vaadin14

Is Vaadin 14 supporting opening multiple browser tabs? When i'm opening new tab in browser then both tabs are working synchornically so when code in one tab is executing then my actions in second tab are waiting for code from 1st tab to end. Is there any way to make both browser card work simultaneously? I still want to allow the user to log in only once per browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaadin acquires a lock for the whole session when processing any request that might change server-side state. If there are multiple UIs belonging to the same session, then they share that lock. This is a fundamental architectural design choice that cannot be circumvented without lots of internal rework.

The recommended way of dealing with this is to avoid doing slow things while holding that lock. This typically means that you submit the actual work to a background thread and then use `UI::access` in combination with `@Push` or `UI::setPollInteval` to make updates to the UI and make those changes available in the browser once the background work is done.

Comment: i made it work by adding `UI.getCurrent().getSession().unlock();` at the begining of creation my panel in one tab, but then i need to write `UI.getCurrent().getSession().lock()`  or `UI.getCurrent().access` whenerver i`m making changes into ui. Is it normal that my session is locked when i'm creating new panel? And is there any option to automatically lock and unlock when changing ui?

Comment: If you manually do `unlock()`, then you are inviting yourself for far more trouble than can possibly imagine. All it takes to corrupt the state of that UI instance is that the user does any other action in the UI (e.g. navigating back in the browser). Once you `lock()` again, you will be overwriting undefined parts of what was done during that intermediary user action.

Comment: Vaadin promises to always hold the session lock on your behalf whenever calling application code related to a specific session. This includes all regular event handlers as well as anything related to navigation. It's thus fully normal that the session is locked when `@Route` classes are instantiated. Without this synchronization from Vaadin, all application code would have to explicitly handle synchronization before touching anything related to the UI state. This would be impractical, prone to mistakes and very unfriendly to beginner. Just use a background thread for slow backed work instead.

Comment: thx for your help, now i know how to do it, and when i move my long loading data to threads then i can do what i want simultaneously in other tabs. But there is another question, is there any option to add some loading spinner into center of grid to tell user that data is still loading?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way of showing a spinner inside Grid itself, but doesn't mean that it's impossible. Might be easier to find an answer if you post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Each browser tab is a different UI but they share the same session. Vaadin 14 doesn't limit opening multiple UIs, but if your login logic is tied to UI, that might.

Comment: i can open multiple tabs but they are working synchornically. In each tab i can see different views

Comment: Vaadin doesn't offer a built-in solution for synchronizing the views, but it also doesn't block you from doing that yourself.